# Is there a way to require a route controller similar to how you require a directive controller?

Tags: angularjs

You are able to tell an Angular directive that it requires a specific directives controller to function using:

```
function SomeDirective() {
    return {
        require: "someOther",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, someOtherCtrl) {
            someOtherCtrl.doSomething();
        }
    };
}

function SomeOtherDirective() {
    return {
        controller: "someOtherCtrl"
    };
}

function SomeOtherCtrl() {}
SomeOtherCtrl.prototype = {
    doSomething: function () {
        console.log("Something");
    }
}

angular.module("some", [])
    .directive("some")
    .directive("someOther")
    .controller("someOtherCtrl");
```

However, I would like to require a controller that is affixed at a route level using **$routeProvider**:

```
$routeProvider.when("/some", {
    templateUrl: "./some.html",
    controller: "someOtherCtrl"
});
```

Is there some way to tell a directive that gets instantiated on the `/some` page that it should get access to **someOtherCtrl** with the `require` attribute?

I figure that if I have to, I can separate the functionality of the **SomeOther** and make it more of a component rather than a route controller which would let me instantiate **SomeOther** as a component on the route page and then tell the **Some** component, a nested element of **SomeOther**, that it needs it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route controllers aren't normal controllers and aren't defined on `ngView` directive, so it i[s not possible to `require` them, but it is possible to fetch it from directive element](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L284-L285):

```
var routeController = $element.data('$ngControllerController');
```

It isn't widespread method of interaction with route controller and have its downsides - a directive is harder to test and becomes unusable outside of the view.

More common and solid alternatives are bindings and scope events.